# why does this function not return decimal?

Tags: sql-server

I want this function to take a datetime and return the time expressed as a decimal.  E.G. - 2:33 PM would be returned as 14.55

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTimeAsDecimal](
@DateTime as datetime
) RETURNS decimal
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @hour decimal
DECLARE @min decimal
DECLARE @result decimal
SELECT @hour = DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTime)
SELECT @min = (DATEPART(MINUTE, @DateTime)/60.0)
SELECT @result = @hour + @min 
RETURN @result
END
```

A similar query produces the results expected...

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, getDate()) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, getDate())/60.0)
```

Comment: Doesn't 2:33 translate to 14.55 (as 33/60 = 0.55)?  Also, if the similar query works, why not use that?

Comment: Yeah, that bit was a typo.  It's corrected.  Do I really need to tell you why I would prefer to have a function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It **does** return a `decimal` - but since you didn't specify a precision and scale, it default to a scale (number of digits after the decimal point) of 0...... so you get a decimal without any digits after the decimal point... (so it'll be rounded and might look like it's not really a decimal - it is).

You need to change all your definitions for `decimal` to something that **does** include a scale! Something like `decimal(18,4)` or something.

A definition of `decimal(18,4)` means:

- a total of 18 digits
- of which 4 digits are after the decimal point (and thus 14 before that)

The default - if you don't specify anything else - is `decimal = decimal(18,0)`

Comment: awesome.  than you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your declarations as follows:

```
DECLARE @hour decimal(4,2)
DECLARE @min decimal(4,2)
DECLARE @result decimal(4,2)
```

Comment: and this bit closed the deal.  thanks.  ended up with...

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTimeAsDecimal](
@DateTime as datetime
) RETURNS decimal(18,2)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CAST(CAST((DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTime)/1.0) as decimal(18,2)) + CAST((DATEPART(MINUTE, @DateTime)/60.0) as decimal(18,2)) as decimal(18,2))
END